# Laravel Framework reset button works to reset form. But how do I call a function after button is clicked?

Tags: laravel

I have a reset button on the bottom of a form in the laravel framework:

```
 <div class="form-group text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" value="<?php echo _AT('apply'); ?>" accesskey="s" />
            <input type="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-danger" value="<?php echo _AT('reset'); ?>"/>
</div>
```

The submit button calls a function via the following in the php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
```

How do I call a function after the reset button is clicked? I want to send a message saying that reset has been clicked so that non-sighted users are notified of the change. I tried this but cannot get it working:

```
if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
    $msg->addFeedback('Preferences have been reset');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I'd recommend not using the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables directly and instead use the $request object included with laravel.*

This will automatically sanitize your user inputs for you.

Here is a rough mock-up of achieving the feature you have mentioned.

[Check here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present) for some further reading on how to use the request object.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// ... 

public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('submit')) {
        //
    }

    if ($request->has('reset')) {
        $resetMessage = 'The form has been reset.';
        return view('path.to.my.view', ['resetMessage' => $resetMessage]);
    }
}
```